# Some source accounts does not exist when using Stellar laboratory with my private Stellar network

Tags: accounts, network

I had some difficulties but I managed to get my private Stellar network to work. Now I try to create accounts with the Stellar Laboratory but every time I send a transaction, I get an error explaining that the **source account doesn't exist** even though it does exist (it's the root). I got the root public address from the secret key and this address has XLM (I looked with horizon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that horizon db hadn't ingested the genesis block. Here is the solution :

https://github.com/zulucrypto/docker-stellar-integration-test-network/issues/8